# SQL Query Result delimit

Tags: mysql

I have a problem like the image.
! [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgfbY.png).

I want to fetch the result of "forQ15aRowList".
I can get that by a simple SQL query.

I need the values [5,2,3,1,4,6] in an array so that I can use these values alone!

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the SQL result, use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (php) or it's variants in whichever language you use to split the string by ',' into an array.

```
$array = explode(',', $result);
```

I do not believe it is possible (or a good idea at that) to do it in pure SQL.